# Sort graph nodes according to their degree

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph G in networkx and would like to sort the nodes according to their degree. However, the following code does not work in latest networkx versions:

```
sorted(set(G.degree().values()))
```

and the following seems a bit clunky as it requires converting the networkx DegreeView to a python list of tuples

```
degrees = [(node,val) for (node, val) in G.degree()]
sorted(degrees, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

is there any better way?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following works:

```
sorted(G.degree, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```